# How to make a grouped histogram with consistent and nicely aligned bins?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to make a histogram of data stored in a `pandas` `DataFrame`, where the histogram is split into two groups according to another column in that dataframe (let's call it the `target` column which can be 1 or 0). I'm having trouble getting the bins for both groups to align in a sensible way.

This is what I have so far:

```
def fun_histByTarget(df, cols, target):
    target = df[target]
    if isinstance(cols, str):
        cols = [cols]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5 * ((len(cols) + 1) // 2)), dpi= 80)
    for i in range(len(cols)):
        sp = fig.add_subplot((len(cols) + 1) // 2, 2, i + 1)
        col = df[cols[i]].copy()
        sp.hist(col[target==0], color='red',  alpha=.3, label='target = 0', align='left')
        sp.hist(col[target==1], color='blue', alpha=.3, label='target = 1', align='left')
        sp.legend()
        sp.set_title(cols[i])
```

This is the result:

```
fun_histByTarget(test, 'integer_col', 'target')
```

[image: result_1]

I've tried manually adding bins with

```
bins = np.linspace(col.values.min(), col.values.max(), 10)
```

But that doesn't help. The resulting bins are very strangely chosen, so that some bars of the histogram fall entirely between two integer values, even though all the data is integer. It's probably because I've hardcoded 10 bins. But it's really hard to choose the correct number of bins automatically. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the same histogram bins for both, it suffices to use the `bins=` parameter with exactly the same boundaries. So, it is very unclear why your test wouldn't work. (It is hard to say without seeing the exact code used.)

Apart from that, the column name 'integer_col' hints at the column only having integers. Histograms are mainly meant to work with continuous data. If you only have integers, and you create bin boundaries as `np.linspace(1, 7, 10)`, there will be 9 bins with weird boundaries  at `[1.0, 1.667, 2.333, 3.0, 3.667, 4.333, 5.0, 5.667, 6.333, 7.0]`. So, integer value 1 will fall in the first bin, value 2 in the second, value 3 either in the third or the fourth (depending on floating point rounding errors), ... A more convenient choice of bins would be at `0.5, 1.5, 2.5, ...` as in the code below. (I also changed `align='left'` to the default `align='mid'` to have the bars at the same spot as their corresponding values.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def fun_histByTarget(df, cols, target):
    target = df[target]
    if isinstance(cols, str):
        cols = [cols]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18, 5 * ((len(cols) + 1) // 2)), dpi=80)
    for i in range(len(cols)):
        ax = fig.add_subplot((len(cols) + 1) // 2, 2, i + 1)
        col = df[cols[i]]
        bins = np.arange(col.min() - 0.5, col.max() + 0.5001, (col.max() - col.max()) // 20 + 1)
        ax.hist(col[target == 0], bins=bins, color='red', alpha=.3, label='target = 0', align='mid')
        ax.hist(col[target == 1], bins=bins, color='blue', alpha=.3, label='target = 1', align='mid')
        ax.legend()
        ax.set_title(cols[i])

target = np.random.randint(0, 2, 100)
integer_col = np.where(target == 0, np.random.randint(1, 7, target.size), np.random.randint(1, 6, target.size))
test = pd.DataFrame({'integer_col': integer_col, 'target': target})
fun_histByTarget(test, 'integer_col', 'target')
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

If you want to avoid overlapping bars, a barplot has many more options, but you'd need to calculate the counts in a separate step (e.g. using `np.hist`, or via `pd.cut`).